# Reference to the music app

Tags: java, android

I am new in Java and I have got small problem, I am writing applications (for android) which is similar to alarm clock and I have a button called set sound, I want to choose sound which will be played, when the alarm will ring,
but I do not want single path to location to music, but I want to this like is in the standard andoid music(standard app), anywhere you paste music file, you do not need look for this, beacuse when you click music app,
it appears in music list. I am doing it onClick method so it is right? I hope that I described my problem properly.

Later, I will try to save this (sound,hours,day of the week), by clicking button save, but I have not done it yet, is something that I should regard?

Sorry for my English

Thanks for help:)

@UP Sorry, here is part of code that is responsible for that:
This is copied from other, but it does not work.

>

```
final Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ContentResolver music = getApplication().getContentResolver();
            Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            Cursor musicCursor = music.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

            String thisPath = null;
            if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int pathColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);


                counter = 0;
                do {
                    thisPath = musicCursor.getString(pathColumn);


                } while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
            }

            File f = new File(thisPath);

            f.getParent();
        }
```

Comment: You forgot to show us your code

Comment: That sounds like a great app *idea*. What specific *problem* are you having with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can get paths of music files by querying songs from MediaStore like in your code. But you need to collect paths into an ArrayList instead of a single "thisPath" String and show them to user using a RecyclerView/ListView. So they can select the music they want.  And you may need to do this in different thread since this is an heavy process which will block your UI thread.

Alternatively you can get an URI of a music file using a music picker by

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

This will open a default player which user can select the music they want.

Comment: Ok, but I do not understand requestCode, I have to change this, add a method  or import class, because it throws me error "cannot resolve symbol".

Comment: It's just an intager you send to the activity so you can uniquely identify whether the result came from right activity. This matters if you are calling  startActivityForResult many time. If not just replace it with 0.

Comment: Thanks for explanations and help with code, I am very happy because it works :) Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. Please accept the answer if it work.

Comment: accept my answer how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Ok, I have one more question, how to install app without usb debugging? Have I make another question or write it here?